# Internal Server Error 500 in Web APi MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I called a HttpPost method from controller to the Web API. For other methods, the response is OK and the method works well except the below mentioned method stating error

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Connection: Close
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2013 09:49:25 GMT
  Server: ASP.NET
  Server: Development
  Server: Server/10.0.0.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  Content-Length: 1855
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

My Method

```
public int CustomerRegistration(CustomerRequestResponse req)
      {
                try
                {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"].ToString());
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    Uri gizmoUri = null;
                    var Response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/MyAccount/CustomerRegistration", req).Result;
                    int result = 0;
                    if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        gizmoUri = Response.Headers.Location;
                        result = Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Int32>().Result;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                catch { throw; }
            }
```

How could I identify where is the mistake in my code. Any suggestions ??

EDIT ::
Traced the error specifying "System.Net.Http.ObjectContent"

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:56003/api/MyAccount/CustomerRegistration', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[ServiceEntities.MyAccount.CustomerRequestResponse, ServiceEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 495
}}
```

Any suggestions for fixing it .?

EDIT1 :

```
</Message><ExceptionMessage>No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'CustomerRequestResponse' from content with media type 'text/plain'.</ExceptionMessage>
```

Comment: Run your API controller in DEBUG. It should stop right on the failing line.  Or set a breakpoint at the top of this method and step through until you error.

Comment: ...sorry -- I missed a key point in your code -- when I want to DEBUG a setup like this one I run two separate instances of VS -- one with the client code and one with the api code.  This makes catching the server side errors pretty easy.  You might also want to consider logging unhandled exeptions with a call stack to Event Log or whereever.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is to verify that the request that the client is doing is correct - correct url, headers, body. In order to do that you can enable `fiddler` as a proxy in your application. Add this section to your `Web.config` and try running the code again with fiddler open - now you should be able to see the request in fiddler:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy  proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />      
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

If the request is ok, check that the server you are trying to connect to is actually up and running and that it's giving you the correct response with correct headers.

I suspect that it should be enough to identify the problem.

BTW: In real life does your `catch` block do something useful actually? To make it more useful than it is now you could add some log4net logging which would probably also help to identify any future issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug while processing data on MyAccountController's CustomerRegistration action. I prefer you to check your controller if there is an error occurring while doing its progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the standard DLL (backend) and Web Script (frontend: such as ashx or aspx, etc.) setup, then it is easy to forget to upload (to the server) a change made to the Web Script.
I received an error like this, however it went away when I made sure that all of my code/script was in-sync and uploaded to the server.